# Predicitve Text in Galaxy Note 2

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an app for s3 , note 2 and nexus 4 . my app have a text which on focus should off the prediction on typing any word. for this i am put these lines of code in xml :

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/start_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Type to search"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
      android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

this piece  `android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"` of code is working perfectly on nexus 4 and s3 but on Note 2 its not working means the prediction is not off on focus (typing in edittext)